# Cannot bind Setting to IsChecked property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I read various articles and tried to implement different solutions, but none appear to work/always lead to the same issue. 
Here's the simplest of my attempts: I used the already predefined Local namespace and try to access the setting (named WantMusic, type Bool, Scope user, value true):

```
<CheckBox x:Name="_wantMusicCB"
    IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static Local:Properties.Settings.Default}, Path=WantMusic, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I get the error that "Key cannot be NULL". Which is hardly descriptive. 
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Somehow the editor appears to swallow the XAML I added... This editor and I will never get to terms...

Comment: `Local` must be `local`.

Comment: Boom. Thank you. And the morale of the story? Don't use IntelliSense that much...

Comment: Don't blame IntelliSense. It would have suggested lowercase `local:`.